# What is the connection string for oledb connection to connect DSN

Tags: vb.net, oledb, dsn

I am trying to connect DSN from my VB 2008 project. When i try using

myoledb.connectionstring="DSN=myDNSname" I get the following error message

An OLEDB provider was not specified in the connectionstring.

Comment: Try This `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DSN=myDNSname`

Comment: @Himal I tried Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as provider but it told me Could not Find Installable ISAM

Comment: _If you use more than 1 extended property then the value tokens must be quoted_ . Found [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8121013/1189040)

Comment: @Prajwal can you please help me in solving this issue. I'm also getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this pages

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/879cc49e-770f-4cbf-906b-7de7ff6fbc1e

http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/ConnectionStrings/OLEDBProviders/tabid/87/Default.aspx

These might be helpful.