# "Could not find installable ISAM" for Jet.OLEDB at connection.Open

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Here is my Connection.cs:

```
public class Connection
{

    public static string connectionstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstr"].ToString();

    public static OleDbConnection DBconnection()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }

}
```

when i enter input values and submit, it shows error something like this,

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdEBB.jpg) is the error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException`: Could not find installable ISAM

I'm new to .NET framework and I just created login.aspx, so I don't have add any source code.

My connection string is

```xml
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="connectionstr" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\registration.mdb;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This might have some useful info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805.

Comment: Look at this which might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562267/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: yes,,   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstr"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\registration.mdb;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: If it's throwing at the opening of the connection string then this might be your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: sorry, i can't get you @GeneralCharismo

Comment: What do you mean? - @Rani

Comment: how can i fix this @GeneralCharismo

Comment: Follow the instruction in the post that I linked and see if it will solve your issue, if you're wondering how to change from Any CPU to x86 you have to right click your project in the solution explorer and go to properties.

Comment: yes.. i m running in 64-bit os..so what to do..

Comment: What are you developing in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93187/discussion-between-rani-and-general-charismo).

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string includes the argument

```
;User Instance=true
```

which does not apply to the Access OLEDB providers (`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` and `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`).

When I included that argument I got the "Could not find installable ISAM" error like you did. When I removed that argument the error went away.

Comment: okay sir.. i changed my code, but now it shows error like this "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." in the line "com.ExecuteNonQuery();" .. what to do?

Comment: That is a different question so you should [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/2144390)